# Tinymce 6.5.1 plugin.min.js issue

Tags: javascript, tinymce-plugins

I have just downloaded the 6.5.1 version. After reading a lot the plugin.min.js is no longer required. However, it still tries to load it.

Used the sample shown in a self-hosted environment:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "#mytextarea",
      plugins: [
        "advlist, autolink, lists, link, image, charmap, print, preview, anchor,",
        "searchreplace, visualblocks, code, fullscreen,",
        "insertdatetime, media, table, paste",
      ],
      toolbar:
        "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    });
</script>
```